# How to implement the "First In First Out" method in a UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uilabel, fifo

I have implemented some Swift code to reveal cells labels one after the other in a `tableView` when the users swipes the screen.

To do so, I have a list of words stored in `words` and only its first item is visible in the `tableView`. Then, when the user swipes the screen, it sets the label of the next cell with the next word from `words`. Scrolling is enabled as `words` contains a long list of words.

In `PlayViewController.swift`, I handle the `UITableView` and the gestures while in `PlayTableViewCell.swift`, I set up the `UITableViewCell`. In `ListViewController.swift`, I ask the user what words he/she wants to store in the `words`array.

***PlayViewController.swift***

```
class PlayViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var playTableView: UITableView!

    var words = [String]()

    var numberOfRevealedLabels = 1

    var numberOfGoodAnswers = 0
    var numberOfWrongAnswers = 0

    var indexGA = 0
    var indexWA = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        playTableView.delegate = self
        playTableView.dataSource = self

        self.playTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 50.0

        view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        let swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.respondToSwipeGesture))
        swipeRight.direction = .right
        view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)

        let swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.respondToSwipeGesture))
        swipeLeft.direction = .left
        view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)

    }

// MARK: Table View Data Source

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return words.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cellIdentifier = "PlayTableViewCell"
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? PlayTableViewCell else {
            fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of PlayTableViewCell.")
        }

        // Configure the cell...
        cell.wordLabel.text = words[indexPath.row]

        cell.wordLabel.isHidden = !(indexPath.row <= numberOfRevealedLabels - 1)

        return cell
    }

    @objc func respondToSwipeGesture(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        if let swipeGesture = gesture as? UISwipeGestureRecognizer {
            switch swipeGesture.direction {
            case UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.right:
                indexGA = numberOfRevealedLabels
                numberOfRevealedLabels += 1
                numberOfGoodAnswers += 1
                playTableView.reloadData()
            case UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.left:
                indexWA = numberOfRevealedLabels
                numberOfRevealedLabels += 1
                numberOfWrongAnswers += 1
                playTableView.reloadData()
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

***PlayTableViewCell.swift***

```
class PlayTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    //MARK: Properties
    @IBOutlet weak var wordLabel: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code

        wordLabel.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping;
        wordLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        wordLabel.isHidden = true

    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state

    }

}
```

***ListViewController.swift***

```
class ListViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var titleTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var nametextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var dataTableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var saveButton: UIBarButtonItem!

    var data = [String]()

    //MARK: Properties
    var list: List?

    //MARK: ViewDidLoad
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Handle the text field’s user input through delegate callbacks.
        titleTextField.delegate = self
        nametextField.delegate = self

        // Set up views if editing an existing List.
        if let list = list {
            navigationItem.title = list.name
            titleTextField.text = list.name
            data = list.content
        }

        // Enable the Save button only if the title field has a valid List name
        updateSaveButtonState()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func addNameToTable(_ sender: Any) {

        guard let word = nametextField.text else {
            return
        }
        data.append(word)
        dataTableView.reloadData()
    }

    @IBAction func playGame(_ sender: Any) {

    }

    //MARK: UITextFieldDelegate

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

        // Disable the Save button while editing
        if (textField == titleTextField) {
            saveButton.isEnabled = false
        } else {
            saveButton.isEnabled = true
        }

    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

        updateSaveButtonState()
        navigationItem.title = titleTextField.text

        guard let word = nametextField.text else {
            return
        }

        if (textField == nametextField) {
            data.append(word)
            dataTableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

        // Hide the keyboard.
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }

    //MARK: Navigation

    @IBAction func cancel(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

        // Depending on style of presentation (modal or push presentation), this view controller needs to be dismissed in two different ways.
        let isPresentingInAddListMode = presentingViewController is UINavigationController

        if isPresentingInAddListMode {

            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else if let owningNavigationController = navigationController{
            owningNavigationController.popViewController(animated: true)
        } else {
            fatalError("The ListViewController is not inside a navigation controller.")
        }
    }

    // This method lets you configure a view controller before it's presented.
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if (segue.identifier == "playGame") {

            // Passing words list to the PlayViewController
            let detailVC = segue.destination as! PlayViewController;
            detailVC.words = data
        }

        super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)

        // Configure the destination view controller only when the save button is pressed.

        guard let button = sender as? UIBarButtonItem, button === saveButton else {
            os_log("The save button was not pressed, cancelling", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)
            return
        }

        let name = titleTextField.text ?? ""

        list = List(name: name, content: data)
    }

    //MARK: Private Methods

    private func updateSaveButtonState() {
        // Disable the Save button if the text field is empty.
        let name = titleTextField.text ?? ""
        saveButton.isEnabled = !name.isEmpty
    }
}

//MARK: Extension

extension ListViewController : UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }// Default is 1 if not implemented

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        return data.count
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")
        cell!.textLabel?.text = data[indexPath.row]
        return cell!
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat{
        return 50
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
        let editAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .default, title: "Edit", handler: { (action, indexPath) in
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "Edit list item", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addTextField(configurationHandler: { (textField) in
                textField.text = self.data[indexPath.row]
            })
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Update", style: .default, handler: { (updateAction) in
                self.data[indexPath.row] = alert.textFields!.first!.text!
                self.dataTableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
            }))
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
            self.present(alert, animated: false)
        })

        let deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .default, title: "Delete", handler: { (action, indexPath) in
            self.data.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            self.dataTableView.reloadData()
        })

        return [deleteAction, editAction]
    }
}
```

And it works fine.

Now, I'd like to prompt each item of `words` ***FIFO-style (First In First Out)*** in a `tableView` with a fixed number of rows.

Let's say I have a 3-rows `tableView`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }
```

And `words` contains 5 items:

```
word1
word2
word3
word4
word5
```

I'd like to display each of them in this order:

```
   First word      Second word        Third word       Fourth word        Fifth word

 ------------      ------------      ------------      ------------      ------------
|   word1    |    |   word1    |    |   word1    |    |   word2    |    |   word3    |
 ------------      ------------      ------------      ------------      ------------
|            |    |   word2    |    |   word2    |    |   word3    |    |   word4    |
 ------------      ------------      ------------      ------------      ------------
|            |    |            |    |   word3    |    |   word4    |    |   word5    |
 ------------      ------------      ------------      ------------      ------------
```

What changes do I need to implement in *PlayViewController.swift* to recreate this FIFO animation?

My goal here is to eliminate the scrolling and make it easier to read, and also to help the swipes as they seem to be undetectable when performed over a scrollable `tableView`.

I'm not sure if I need to rewrite a bigger part of my code or changing a few lines in *PlayViewController.swift* could do the trick.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: is that not fifo? first word in is word1 first word out is word1 lifo would mean the last word to be added to the list would be the first one out, so from third to fourth the one that should be gone is word 3 in lifo, is that correct you want lifo or fifo?

Comment: That's really FIFO. Where are you appending or removing Sting value from and to your array? Or your could quite well just disable scrollView of the Table view and scroll to last index for this to work (your data will still have all the values though).

Comment: Dammit you're right, it's totally FIFO in here @Nero, I just edited my post. Sorry for the mix-up!

Comment: @SWAT I push the words in ```words``` array in a different view called ListViewController.swift. I'm updating my question with this code.

Comment: i have another question then, thats more or less the default behavior of a scrollview do you need to remove the first words once the user see the 4rth?

Comment: @Nero in this example, I'd like to remove only the first word to "make room" for the 4th word in the last row of the table: in the first row, I'd like to replace the first word by the second; in the second row, the second by the third; in the third & last row, the third by the fourth. Does that make sense?

Comment: but you don't need to do that, table views do that by default, they just move (scroll) to make room for new rows as you scroll and you can scroll back up to see the rest, thats the whole point of making a tableview, just replace the func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }
for a return with the amount of items in your data array

Comment: @Nero I've tried it and it doesn't, to me it's just the first step of a bigger modification of the code. All it does is to constraint the display of the first 3 cells but it doesn't affect the update of the labels. The three first labels are displayed and when you keep swiping, nothing changes as to my understanding, the cells keep being updated but they just don't appear anymore in the tableView due to the limited number of rows.

Comment: you are doing something wrong, i will add an answer with a regular implementation of a table view wich does exactly what you want

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204951/discussion-between-dfatpunk-and-nero).